# Executing events from both page and directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I have two modules, one for the actual page and the other for building reusable components. I have a button in my custom directive which does action A. I'm using this this directive inside another module page where I have action B which has to be executed once the directive button is clicked.

So it should do something like below:

> dir button click -> function A() + function B() in page.

**Broadcasting seems to be unorthodox in the environment I work in.**

I've tried in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywgRXwLDbvjcmKbqCdMH?p=preview).

Here's what the code looks like:

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('diruser', ['dir'])
  .controller('dirusercon', function($scope) {
    $scope.clicks = function(ev) {
      console.log('click from page');
      console.log(ev);
    };
  });

angular.module('dir', [])
  .controller('dircon', function($scope) {
    $scope.dirclick = function(ev) {
      console.log('click from dir');
    }
  })
  .directive('dire', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'dircon',
      scope: {
        dirclicked: '&'
      },
      template: "<button ng-click='dirclick($event)'>OK</button>"
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='diruser' ng-controller='dirusercon'>
    
    <dire dirclick='clicks(e)'></dire>
  </body>

</html>
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample, there is mistake :

You defined in scope a function named dircliked, but you use it as dirclick.

The use must be : `<dire dirclicked='clicks(e)'></dire>`

In your dirClick function you must call dircliked in scope :

```
$scope.dirclick = function(ev){
   console.log('click from dir');
   $scope.dirclicked({e: ev});
}
```

I edited your plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/2L7ezlPKcChQfulZZtx0?p=preview